# php sql recordeseet unable to connect by variable

Tags: php, javascript, sql, variables, record

`<form name="form1"/>`

`<input type="text" name="code1" value="D50" size="7" maxlength="10" onblur="chkidpro(this.value,'provider1');" />`

`<input type="text" name="code2" value="" size="7" maxlength="10"/>`

`<form/>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`

`var jvalue = form1.code1.value;`

`<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(jvalue)</script>"?>`

`</script>`

`<?PHP $con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc_one","PASS");`

`mysql_select_db("abc_one", $con);`

`$c= "D50";`

`$jval = $abc;`

`$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblprocode where code='". $c."';");`

`$tab = mysql_fetch_array($result2);`

`$fld1 = $tab['card'];`

`mysql_close($con);`

`?>`

`<?php echo $jval; ?>`

`<?php echo $fld1; ?>`

***if i replace*** `$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblprocode where code='". $jval."';");`

`<?php echo $abc; ?> // its print as D50`

`<?php echo $jval; ?> // its print as D50`

`<?php echo $fld1; ?> // its not print, its blank`

***if i replace*** `$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblprocode where code='". $c."';");`

`<?php echo $abc; ?> // its print as D50`

`<?php echo $jval; ?> // its print as D50`

`<?php echo $fld1; ?> // its print record data`

**please help me what is the wrong??**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `trim` function `$jval = trim($abc);`

Comment: Thank you for your help, its not success, 

`<?PHP`

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc_one","pass");`

`mysql_select_db("abc_one", $con);`

`echo 'abc is_' .$abc; echo 'abc is_' .$abc; // ITS DISPLAY AS abc is_D50abc is_D50 so no TRIM ISSUE`

`$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblprocode where code='". $c ."';");`

`$tab = mysql_fetch_array($result2);`

`$fld1 = $tab['card'];`

`mysql_close($con);`

`?>`

`<?php echo $jval; ?> // ITS PRINT AS D10`

`<?php echo $fld1; ?> // ITS BLANK`

Comment: **THANK YOU FOR HELP, BUT ITS NOT SUCCESS**`echo 'abc is_' .$abc; echo 'abc is_' .$abc; // ITS DISPLAY AS abc is_D50abc is_D50 so no TRIM ISSUE`